# Flutter and Firebase Connection stops at Firebase.initializeApp()

Tags: android, ios, flutter, firebase, dart

I am devoloping a multi platform app using flutter for android and ios. Now I am trying to connect my app with Firebase. I did every necessary steps including, adding google_services.json, adding firebase core, auth, core web, cloud firestore. But for some reason my app stops at the line `await Firebase.initializeApp();`. its shows the error `Error: Assertion failed:`.

Here is my `main.dart`

```
import 'package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'features/auth/welcome_screen.dart';

Future main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  print("////////////////////////////////");
  await Firebase.initializeApp();
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'UniCompanion',
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: WelcomeScreen(),
    );
  }
}
```

and here is the error:

```
Error: Assertion failed:
file:///C:/Users/rudro/AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/firebase_core_web-2.4.0/li
b/src/firebase_core_web.dart:256:11
C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/out/host_debug/dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/priva
te/ddc_runtime/errors.dart 266:49  throw_
C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/out/host_debug/dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/priva
te/ddc_runtime/errors.dart 29:3    assertFailed
packages/firebase_core_web/src/firebase_core_web.dart 256:18
initializeApp
C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/out/host_debug/dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/patch
/async_patch.dart 45:50            <fn>
C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/out/host_debug/dart-sdk/lib/async/zone.dart 1660:54       
runUnary
C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/out/host_debug/dart-sdk/lib/async/future_impl.dart 147:18 
handleValue
C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/out/host_debug/dart-sdk/lib/async/future_impl.dart 767:44 
handleValueCallback
C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/out/host_debug/dart-sdk/lib/async/future_impl.dart 796:13 
_propagateToListeners
C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/out/host_debug/dart-sdk/lib/async/future_impl.dart 567:5  
[_completeWithValue]
C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/out/host_debug/dart-sdk/lib/async/future.dart 528:22      
<fn>
C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/out/host_debug/dart-sdk/lib/async/zone.dart 1660:54       
runUnary
C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/out/host_debug/dart-sdk/lib/async/future_impl.dart 147:18 
handleValue
C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/out/host_debug/dart-sdk/lib/async/future_impl.dart 767:44 
handleValueCallback
C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/out/host_debug/dart-sdk/lib/async/future_impl.dart 796:13 
_propagateToListeners
C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/out/host_debug/dart-sdk/lib/async/future_impl.dart 567:5  
[_completeWithValue]
C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/out/host_debug/dart-sdk/lib/async/future_impl.dart 640:7  
callback
C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/out/host_debug/dart-sdk/lib/async/schedule_microtask.dart 
40:11                              _microtaskLoop
C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/out/host_debug/dart-sdk/lib/async/schedule_microtask.dart 
49:5                               _startMicrotaskLoop
C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/out/host_debug/dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/patch
/async_patch.dart 166:15           <fn>
```

Please help me with this.

I tried to add all dependencies such as adding these line in `pubspec.yaml` file

```
  firebase_auth: ^4.5.0
  cloud_firestore: ^4.6.0
  firebase_analytics: ^10.3.0
  firebase_core: ^2.11.0
  firebase_core_web: ^2.4.0
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're missing the configuration for the web app, which needs to be inside JavaScript file as shown in this documentation on [initializing the Flutter SDK for Firebase for a web app](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/manual-installation#web).

Honestly, I'd nowadays recommend putting the initialization in the Dart code - by following the setup instructions in [adding Firebase to your Flutter app](https://firebase.google.com/docs/flutter/setup?platform=web#initialize-firebase).

Answer (score 0):

In your main.dart in the void main(runApp()) section add this and try

```
await Firebase.initializeApp(
  options: DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform,
);
```